# Como alterar uma consulta para que a mesma seja executada por cada linha da tabela X?

Tags: mysql, query

Tenho a seguinte consulta à base de dados a funcionar:

```sql
SET @orderid := '1';

INSERT INTO `cart_lines` ( `line_id` , `cart_id` , `book_id` , `book_reference` , `book_name` , `book_type` , `unit_price` , `quantity` , `date_created` , `date_updated` ) 
SELECT
  A.id AS line_id,
  CONCAT( @orderid ) AS cart_id,
  A.pid AS book_id,
  C.ref AS book_reference,
  C.name_prt AS book_name,
  concat( 'impresso' ) AS book_type,
  A.unit_price AS unit_price,
  A.qtd AS quantity,
  D.end_time AS date_created,
  D.end_time AS dade_updated
FROM table_eshop_lines A
INNER JOIN table_books C ON ( A.pid = C.id ) 
INNER JOIN table_eshop D ON ( D.id = @orderid ) 
WHERE INSTR( (
  SELECT concat( ';', lines_id, ';' ) AS ids
  FROM table_eshop
  WHERE id =@orderid ) , concat( ';', A.id, ';' ) 
) > 0
```

Na sua forma atual, é preciso atualizar o valor da variavel `orderid` com o valor da coluna `id` da tabela `table_esop` para cada linha existente *(processo manual)*.

## Pergunta

Como posso alterar esta consulta de forma a que a mesma seja executada por cada linha da tabela `table_eshop` ?

---

<sup>**Notas:**

Todos os dados necessários estão na presente consulta, mas se for preciso apresentar informação adicional sobre as tabelas, por favor deixar um comentário na pergunta e eu agirei em conformidade.</sup>

Comment: De onde vem o `lines_id`?

Comment: @bfavaretto Vem da tabela de onde está a ser seleccionado, a `table_eshop`. A estrutura da tabela pode ser vista nesta pergunta [aqui](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/978/como-selecionar-linhas-da-tabela-a-que-estao-referenciadas-numa-coluna-da-tabela).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que a consulta pode ser simplificada assim (ou entendi errado o contexto):

```sql
INSERT INTO `cart_lines` ( `line_id` , `cart_id` , `book_id` , `book_reference` , `book_name` , `book_type` , `unit_price` , `quantity` , `date_created` , `date_updated` ) 
SELECT
  A.id AS line_id,
  D.id AS cart_id,
  A.pid AS book_id,
  C.ref AS book_reference,
  C.name_prt AS book_name,
  concat( 'impresso' ) AS book_type,
  A.unit_price AS unit_price,
  A.qtd AS quantity,
  D.end_time AS date_created,
  D.end_time AS dade_updated
FROM table_eshop_lines A
INNER JOIN table_books C ON ( A.pid = C.id ) 
INNER JOIN table_eshop D 
ON FIND_IN_SET(A.id, REPLACE(D.lines_id, ';', ',')) > 0
WHERE 1=1;
```

[Demo simplificado](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d534ff/12) no SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade é utilizar um [`CURSOR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cursors.html).

Abaixo segue um exemplo de como seu código poderia ser implementado utilizando um Cursor dentro de uma `PROCEDURE`.

```sql
-- Não testado
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_tb_eshop()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE orderid INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM table_eshop;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO orderid;

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO `cart_lines` ( `line_id` , `cart_id` , `book_id` , `book_reference` , `book_name` , `book_type` , `unit_price` , `quantity` , `date_created` , `date_updated` ) 
    SELECT
      A.id AS line_id,
      CONCAT( @orderid ) AS cart_id,
      A.pid AS book_id,
      C.ref AS book_reference,
      C.name_prt AS book_name,
      concat( 'impresso' ) AS book_type,
      A.unit_price AS unit_price,
      A.qtd AS quantity,
      D.end_time AS date_created,
      D.end_time AS dade_updated
    FROM table_eshop_lines A
    INNER JOIN table_books C ON ( A.pid = C.id ) 
    INNER JOIN table_eshop D ON ( D.id = @orderid ) 
    WHERE INSTR( (
      SELECT concat( ';', lines_id, ';' ) AS ids
      FROM table_eshop
      WHERE id = @orderid ) , concat( ';', A.id, ';' ) 
    ) > 0
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Ao testar, dá-me um erro para verificar a syntax junto de '' na linha `DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;`

Comment: @Zuul, não consigo visualizar o erro. Até porque a base deste código é da própria documentação de `CURSOR` no site do MySQL. Realmente o [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) relata um erro ao testar o código.